# BLDC cogs and turns when helped with hand

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller

I am working on a project where i am using a big bldc motor with an ESC.
The motor is still new and runs well : [Motor link](https://ozo-electric.com/fr/moteurs-roues-brushless/827-moteur-electrique-roue-5-125mm-150w-12v-24v-36v-chariot-de-golf-ou-poussette.html)

I am using this ESC with the motor : [ESC link](https://www.amazon.fr/Brushless-Controller-Quadcopter-Multirotor-Helicopter/dp/B086YNKTH8/ref=sr_1_3_sspa?__mk_fr_FR=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&dchild=1&keywords=esc%2050A%206S&qid=1624459824&sr=8-3-spons&psc=1&spLa=ZW5jcnlwdGVkUXVhbGlmaWVyPUExRjRNSVJVVEhaRVJZJmVuY3J5cHRlZElkPUEwOTQwNjcxM1BVMlFWOUJRWksyMiZlbmNyeXB0ZWRBZElkPUEwMjcyOTk4MUFHMlA4QzJHVkMyMSZ3aWRnZXROYW1lPXNwX2F0ZiZhY3Rpb249Y2xpY2tSZWRpcmVjdCZkb05vdExvZ0NsaWNrPXRydWU=)

So the esc is working fine with a small motor but witht his motor it does not, the motor cogs but when i help turning it with my hand it starts turning right, when i stop the motor and try to run it again the same thing happens.

I need help to understand what s happening.

Thanks.

Comment: Sensored or sensorless? Sensorless controllers may need tuning to match system inertia during the open loop start routine.

Comment: Hey @user_1818839 it is sensorless. So absically i am using an Arduino to provide the PWM signal, i tried to do the process of calibrating the esc but does not seem to work.